# How to disable repeating messages about PPPoE in minicom?

Tags: linux, router, pppoe

I use minicom to connect router via usb. I send commands and watch results. All is good. But every few seconds minicome generate messages:

```
Unable to complete PPPoE Discovery                                                                                    
Terminating on signal 15                                                                                              
loading pppoe plugin ...                                                                                              
RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.3 compiled against pppd 2.4.4
```

How to disable it? Help.

**UPD:** I stopped messages by means of "killall -9 pppd" executing

Answer (score 0):

That is not minicom. That is the kernel. You can try to switch off console messages using the command:

```
echo "4 1 1 7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

But they just disappear from the console. There will be the messages in log files anyway.

Comment: I ran the command, but the messages continue to appear. I also watch printk file content. His only string is "4 1 1 7"

Comment: After executing "killall -9 pppd" messages disappeared.